# My graphic drivers are gone

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xorg, xubuntu

I am on Xubuntu 13.10 64 bit. [This question tells you everything you need to know about my graphic card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417826/which-graphics-divers-should-i-use).

Yesterday I had a problem, my graphic card driver failed, now if I login to xubuntu default desktop, all I see is a black screen however I can login to xfce session

The output of `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller 
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] 
           X.Org: 1.14.5 drivers: fglrx,intel Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6400M Series GLX Version: 4.2.12337 - CPC 13.101
```

[image]

[image]

`xsession-errors`

```
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Xsession: X session started for elie at Mon Mar 10 10:16:26 EET 2014
localuser:elie being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
gnome-session-is-accelerated: llvmpipe detected.
x-session-manager[2113]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Xsession: X session started for elie at Mon Mar 10 10:17:23 EET 2014
localuser:elie being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
gnome-session-is-accelerated: llvmpipe detected.
x-session-manager[2466]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old](http://pastebin.com/Qfug7buq) and [/etc/X11/xorg.conf](http://pastebin.com/qN61CikD). Note that I no longer  have xorg.conf, because I followed the answers below, but even if I generate new file, It will be looking like the file above, I tried it.

Comment: Very strange. Try `sudo apt-get install -f`, then `sudo apt-get purge jockey-gtk` followed by `sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk`. Does Additional Drivers work now?

Comment: @landroni no still the same error

Comment: What does `whereis jockey-gtk` output?

Comment: @landroni `whereis jockey-gtk` outputs `Jockey-gtk:` so as if it wasn't installed

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with PATHs. Here it outputs: `jockey-gtk: /usr/bin/jockey-gtk /usr/bin/X11/jockey-gtk`. Try `/usr/bin/jockey-gtk`.

Comment: @landroni `bash: /usr/bin/jockey-gtk: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please [install `inxi`](http://code.google.com/p/inxi/wiki/Installation) if you don't have it and post the output of `inxi -G`. The fact that you have the `fglrx` driver installed does not mean that you're actually using it.

Comment: @terdon http://www.hastebin.com/rujetemomi.avrasm

Comment: OK, you have 2 cards, which one are you actually using? This is usually set in the BIOS. If you're using the ATI one, have you installed `aticonfig`? Also, do you have an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file? Did you try going to software sources as described in my answer?

Comment: @terdon I updated my question, doesn't that mean that I am using the AMD?

Comment: Yes, looks like it. It also looks like the module is both working an loaded. OK, try logging into the default session again, and then post the contents of `~/.xsession-errors`, that will tell us what error you are experiencing. You might also want to remove all the stuff about `jockey-gtk` since it's not relevant and you now know how to access jockey's functionality. Even better, come into the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) room where we can discuss more easily.

Comment: @terdon I updated the question, I don't know how to use chat, I see many users, how to ask and  who will answer and so on

Comment: Just click on [this link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13552/discussion-between-terdon-and-fischer) to get a "private" conversation (anyone can see it mind you, it's just a separate room). It looks like X is trying to load `i965`, the intel driver. Do you have an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file?

Comment: Can you post also your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`?

Comment: @terdon please read my edit, Ill leave the same link in chat if you want to discuss it there, it's not a real time chat I think so I'll reply whenever I have time

Comment: @Braiam please read my edit

Comment: @Fischer see updated answer.

Comment: @Fischer --- you're graphic adapter is practically the same of mine. I managed to get it working there: http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395 --- no way to have it working for me with the proprietary drivers.

Comment: @Rmano I updated my question, I'll try to follow your answer and get back to you, the proprietary drivers were working fine on my PC, until that problem. if it doesn't work, it's okay 14.04 is coming in less than a month and I'm going to install it anyway so no big deal, but it would be great if the issue can be fixed

Comment: It's really strange, because from the logs seems that the X server is happily running, but you get an error by libGL which is I suppose from `libgl1-mesa-*` packages --- have you had some recent update on them?

Comment: @Rmano I do update and upgrade packages from terminal, I don't know if they were updated, I also remove lots of stuff regularly with autoremove and autoclean

Comment: @Rmano I'm not that experienced with linux, not as much as you guys, but I think it's not about graphic card, it's about xubuntu, I think there's something wrong with the desktop environment, something like that

Answer (score 3):

Your `xorg.conf` has two device sections:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "intel"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

This is causing your machine to attempt to load both the `fglrx` and the `intel` drivers. While it is actually possible to use multiple graphics cards on Linux, I doubt you can do that with an integrated (intel) and a dedicated (ATI) one. It is very likely that removing the `intel` section will return everything to normal (assuming the `fglrx` driver works on your system but as I understand it used to, so it probably will). So, comment out the `intel` section and keep only `fglrx`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

#Section "Device"
#    Identifier  "intel"
#    Driver      "intel"
#    Option      "AccelMethod" "uxa"
#EndSection
```

Then restart X and, assuming there is no other issue, everything should be fine.

If not, you can try creating a new `xorg.conf` using ATI's configuration tool, `aticonfig`:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

If you do go down this road, I also recommend you read through that program's options, they're quite extensive:

```
aticonfig --help | less
```

Finally, the [Arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst) on ATI/AMD cards is a great source of information on this kind of thing.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, commenting these lines will cause ubuntu to boot into tty

Comment: @Fischer damn, something very strange in your setup. OK, try the `aticonfig` apporach, also try commenting out the `fglrx` section and using the intel one instead. Your system seems to be confused about which card to use. Finally, check your BIOS settings, which card is activated there? Do you have it set to software switching?

Comment: So far I have tried `sudo aticonfig --initial`, it created `xorg.conf` similar to the one I have so the issue is still there, I will try to comment fglrx, btw I enter bios and I see nothing about my graphic card, there's stuff like the serial number of the pc, the wireless module, nothing about the graphic card, I'm on hp pavillion g6

Comment: I tried to comment out `fglrx` did not work

Comment: @terdon, he has an hybrid card; it's quite common on recent laptops and a PITA in Linux most of the time :-| --- I know, I have one that make the installation disk of Ubuntu overheat and shutdown the system in seconds.

Comment: @Rmano is that a hybrid card (is that a thing?) or 2 separate cards? One integrated and one discrete?

Comment: @terdon probably. See here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI#Hybrid_graphics.2FAMD_Dynamic_Switchable_Graphics --- the Ubuntu link is somewhat outdated https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics . I suppose this is a way to add an high performance card and using the integrated graphics of the i3/5/7 processors too.

Comment: @Rmano exactly, that's two separate cards. From the arch wiki you linked to : "It is the technology used on recent laptops equiped with two GPUs,". When I had a similar setup, I could use my nvidia alone by disabling the onboard one in thew BIOS. This is not a single card but to separate ones (well, one separate and one integrated anyway).

Comment: @terdon yes. Unfortunately there must be a competition about who wrote the worst BIOS --- which my Samsung probably will win hands down. No option in BIOS even mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to purge the GC drivers and reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx fglrx-pxpress

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

If that doesn't fix it, time to  edit XConfigs!

Comment: Didn't  work, and this is the output if you want to see it http://www.hastebin.com/talitexeru.vhdl

Comment: After the purge, you have to manually remove /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. It is not deleted automatically... that solved my problem when going back to open-source drivers.

Comment: @Rmano  tried that yesterday again, did not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to uninstall first your third-party driver.
Then try delete`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot.
XSERVER will create a new one.

Comment: tried that yesterday again, did not work

Comment: Could you post a video link with the start up sequence?

Comment: nothing worth filming, normal booting no errors, after logging in i see http://imgur.com/nSsgpCm

Comment: To go back to open source drivers, you have to purge `fglrx` and `fglrx-pxpress` to (or they `-update` equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark --- let's suppose is not the graphic drivers. What is failing seems to be the `x-session-manager` script, due to a bug in libGL.

So I would try:

1) calling manually `startx` in a terminal. If the graphic screen appears, the drivers are working ok, and the problem is somewhere else. (You'll probably have just one naked terminal in it).

2) Try to reconfigure `gdm` or `lightdm`. By the way, I could not start xubuntu desktop with lightdm windows manager, I had to install gdm. So could be

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

And/or the corresponding `sudo apt-get install gdm` if you do not have it.

3) going deeper, it may be the 3D graphics failing. Have you installed `xorg-edgers` or something like that? Maybe it is a recent bug in it.

4) and as a last resort, you can try some non-accelerated desktop, like Gnome classic or Ubuntu 2D.

5) Try to login as a guest user to see if the problem is related to some strange configuration file.

6) and as a voodoo-kind of thing: check is there is some strange dot file (with  `ls - lad .*`) owned by root stick in your home dir --- I once had a $DEITY-know-how-was-there `.Xauthority` file owned by root that blocked all my logins...

Hope this helps... but probably not.

Comment: `sudo startx` will give a black screen so I'd have to go to tty to restart gdm, does that mean it's a graphic card issue?

Comment: And if you restart gdm you have a login screen?

Comment: yes if i restart gdm i have a login screen, lightdm doesn't work